# Can't get it to work: Use value from one javascript function in another function

Tags: javascript

I'm practising with several javascript functions, which all work fine separately. But if I try to get a value from one function into another function I can't get it to work. 
I've read multiple threads overhere (and elsewhere) and have been trying with several options like 'return', 'callback', console.log, merging the functions, etc. 
No result for me... Could you help me?

My fiddle is:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2g5ong/)

I would like to use the value of variable 'direction' inside `function geo()` in another function: `processSVData()`. In processSVData I would use the direction 2 times.

Comment: Can you add your code here as a working snippet demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inside your question.

Comment: Wohh what a mix of things here... Console.log, callback, return... Do you know what you are doing? Please read some reference before posting here, so that you can understand the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the function which accesses the `direction` variable accesses it before it is set. I've changed script ordering here and it works fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/bz2g5ong/7/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read the code but, as a general idea:

```
function iNeedData(preciousData) {
    console.log(preciousData);
}

function iSendData() {
    iNeedData("Wow, data!");
}

iSendData();
```

Comment: I'm new to javascript and have a language-conflict when reading the limitless amount of info and all possibilities. So do I know what I'm doing: partly and that's why I'm practising.

Comment: Thanks @mehulmpt, that's the result I was looking for. window.direction and initMap();.... never thought about that